# How to correctly use page components without GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have a new Gatsby site, which has 3 pages (with more to come). I am finding that I am having to repeat lots of styling and I know there must be a correct way to avoid doing this but I'm unsure what. I'm using Emotion with Tailwind.

There is a hero element on all pages, which include a heading and description:

```
<Hero>
  <Title>
    Page title here
  </Title>
  <Lead>
    Descirption text here
  </Lead>
</Hero>
```

This is the styling for it:

```
const Hero = styled.header`
  ${tw`bg-blue-dark p-6`};
`
const Title = styled.h1`
  ${tw`text-white tracking-wide font-medium`};
`
const Lead = styled.p`
  ${tw`text-gray leading-relaxed mb-1`};
  a {
    ${tw`text-white font-medium no-underline text-purple hover:text-white`};
  }
`
```

Some pages also have action buttons:

```
<Actions>
  <LinkPrimary to="/some-page/">Click for more</LinkPrimary>
  <LinkSecondary to="/some-other-page/">Or click here</LinkSecondary>
</Actions>
```

Full page template looks like (this is what I'm duplicating for every new page):

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import styled from "@emotion/styled"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import tw from "tailwind.macro"

const Hero = styled.header`
  ${tw`bg-blue-dark p-6`};
`
const Title = styled.h1`
  ${tw`text-white tracking-wide font-medium`};
`
const Lead = styled.p`
  ${tw`text-gray leading-relaxed mb-1`};
  a {
    ${tw`text-white font-medium no-underline text-purple hover:text-white`};
  }
`
const Actions = styled.section`
  ${tw`text-center m-2 mt-8 mb-24`};
`
const LinkPrimary = styled(Link)`
  ${tw`block bg-pink hover:bg-green-light text-blue-dark font-bold no-underline py-4 px-4 m-4 rounded`}
`
const LinkSecondary = styled(Link)`
  ${tw`block bg-regal-blue hover:bg-blue-light text-pink hover:text-white font-semibold no-underline py-4 px-4 m-4 rounded`}
`

export default () => (
  <Layout>
    <Hero>
      <Title>
        Hey I'm The About Page
      </Title>
      <Lead>
        Learn all about us 
      </Lead>
    </Hero>
    <Actions>
      <LinkPrimary to="/some-page/">Click for more</LinkPrimary>
      <LinkSecondary to="/some-other-page/">Or click here</LinkSecondary>
    </Actions>
  </Layout>
)
```

The problem I have is for every new page I have to repeat the styling. I am manually creating these pages within `src/pages` and editing the title and description for each page. Pages that have the buttons I am also editing the button text and URL.

I'm guessing there must be a way to create a "hero" component which includes the title and lead with their styling, then import it into each page and edit the content on a per-page basis.

Not all pages will have the action buttons so they probably need to be in their own component and just imported where needed.

If someone could give me a basic demo or link to some docs where this is explained that would be much appreciated. All my research only gives [examples of how to do this querying with GraphQL](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/).

Comment: Do you just want to abstract the duplicated code into it's own component? Where does the data come from?

Comment: Yes, putting it into a reusable component sounds like the best method. I'm typing the data into the html.

Comment: Do you have a repository that you can share?

Comment: @ksav I will see if I can get a repo up but essentially what I have is [this](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/emotion/) where you can see there is a `src/pages/index.js` with its styling. Now imagine you wanted to create a page called "Users" you would first duplicate the index page and rename it to `src/pages/users.js` and herein begins the problem, you have to maintain the same styling across both these files. Another way to describe this is; I have a page template which I'm using for multiple pages, each page has different content but they all use the same styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I think I have something that works so will post an answer.

Create a Hero component `src/components/hero.js`

```
import React from "react"
import styled from "@emotion/styled"
import tw from "tailwind.macro"

const Header = styled.header`
  ${tw`p-6`};
`
const Title = styled.h1`
  ${tw`text-white tracking-wide text-lg font-medium`};
`
const Lead = styled.p`
  ${tw`text-purple-light leading-relaxed text-lg`};
`
const Hero = props => (
  <Header>
    <Title>{props.heading}</Title>
    <Lead>{props.text}</Lead>
  </Header>
)

export default Hero
```

Then use it in your pages, index page, about page, wherever it's needed:

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Hero from "../components/hero"

export default () => (
  <Layout>
    <Hero
      heading="Hello world!"
      text="This is the lead text for this page."
    />
...
  </Layout>
)
```

The great thing about this is now my styling for my hero element is all contained in my Hero component. I will probably do the same for the call to action buttons.

If you want to have links or html tags in your text, you can do the following:

```
<Hero
      heading={[<em>Links</em>, " that", <br />, " go places"]}
      text={[
        "You can write some text here followed by ",
        <Link to="/learn/">
          a link to another page
        </Link>,
        " that you can click.",
      ]}
    />
```